# How to remove new lines in dataframe while writing xml into it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write `xml` response from an `api`, iterating over `tag` TrackingEvent and saving into a `dataframe`:

The `xml` response looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrackingResult>
   <Events>
      <TrackingEvent>
         <DateTimeStamp>202010</DateTimeStamp>
         <Event>Delivered</Event>
         <ExtraInfo>02921</ExtraInfo>
      </TrackingEvent>
      <TrackingEvent>
         <DateTimeStamp>202010</DateTimeStamp>
         <Event>Delivery today</Event>
         <ExtraInfo>31916</ExtraInfo>
      </TrackingEvent>
   </Events>
   <Signatures />
   <Errors />
</TrackingResult>
```

I am writing this into a dataframe using this code :

```
response_status = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print(type(response_status)) #<class 'requests.models.Response'>
print(type(response_status.content)) #<class 'bytes'>

tree = ET.fromstring(response_status.content)
for child in tree.iter('TrackingEvent'):
    for elem in child.iter():
         data = {str(elem.tag):[elem.text]}
         if str(elem.text)=='None' :continue
         response_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
         consolidated_list.append(response_df) 
consolidated_df = pd.concat(consolidated_list,ignore_index=True)
print(consolidated_df)
```

This is the output `dataframe` i'm getting :

```
DateTimeStamp            Event              ExtraInfo
202010
                        Delivered            
                                             02921
202010
                        Delivery today
                                             31916
```

I want to remove these empty spaces to put one child iteration into a single dataframe row

expected output:

```
DateTimeStamp            Event              ExtraInfo
202010                   Delivered          02921
202010                   Delivery today     31916
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to build a dict in a loop and then create dataframe on basis of that dict. Here is an example:

```
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<TrackingResult>
   <Events>
      <TrackingEvent>
         <DateTimeStamp>202010</DateTimeStamp>
         <Event>Delivered</Event>
         <ExtraInfo>02921</ExtraInfo>
      </TrackingEvent>
      <TrackingEvent>
         <DateTimeStamp>202010</DateTimeStamp>
         <Event>Delivery today</Event>
         <ExtraInfo>31916</ExtraInfo>
      </TrackingEvent>
   </Events>
   <Signatures />
   <Errors />
</TrackingResult>'''

from lxml import etree as ET
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
for child in tree.iter('TrackingEvent'):
    for elem in child.iter():
        if (elem.text is not None and str(elem.text).strip() != ''):
            d[elem.tag].append(elem.text.strip())
        else:
            if len(list(elem)) == 0:
                d[elem.tag].append(None)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  DateTimeStamp           Event ExtraInfo
0        202010       Delivered     02921
1        202010  Delivery today     31916
```

Comment: `d[elem.tag].append(elem.text.strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: Updated answer with checks for none type and XML leafs.

Comment: this worked ..thank you..Could you expalin the `else` part ?

Comment: In the `else` part we check if element is a leaf in terms of XML (i.e. hasn't child elements). This allows to skip e.g. `TrackingEvent` elements, but handle situations, when one of the `DateTimeStamp`, `Event` or `ExtraInfo` tags is empty or self-closing (like <Event/>). In lxml `list(element)` returns element child nodes, so `len()` of it should be 0 when no children are present.